# pod does not become running within 10 min, how to exit it directly (will never become running)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, spring-cloud-dataflow

Use spring cloud data flow to pull up a batch pod. In some cases, the pod is always pending. At this point, the developer thinks that the container failed to pull up and re-pull a pod, but the original pending pod's conditions are re-satisfied, The status changes to running, then my batch program is run twice.

The problem detail can be list below:
the pod scheduled by scdf(spring cloud data flow) needed to mount glusterfs volume, in some time, the glusterfs server was down, and the pod status Backoff sync for timeout to mount. With glusterfs server running, then the backoff sync pod cloud be running also, and the problem appear.

Comment: you have to provide more information. otherwise, others will not understand your problem. explain what you were doing. what error you were getting. how you re-satisfied pod's condition. add output of `kubectl describe <your pod>`.

Comment: Your suggestion benefits me, thanks!